# Error defining a templated operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

Here's an attempted templated overload of operator+. This fails to compile with both gcc 4.8 and icc 14.0.3.

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
  B operator+(const B& rhs)
  {
    return *this;
  }
};

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  operator B<T>() const{return B<T>();}
};

// template<typename T>                                                                                                                                                        
// B<T> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)                                                                                                                                
// {                                                                                                                                                                           
//   return (B<T>)t + (B<T>)u;                                                                                                                                                 
// }                                                                                                                                                                           

template<typename T, typename U>
B<U> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)
{
  return (B<U>)t + (B<U>)u;
}

int main()
{
  A<double> a,b;
  B<double> c = a+b;
  return 0;
}
```

However, the commented overload works fine. What is the difference? Why doesn't the template with two parameters match?

```
g++48 -std=c++11 temp2.cpp
temp2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp2.cpp:33:18: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘A<double>’ and ‘A<double>’)
   B<double> c = a+b;
                  ^
temp2.cpp:33:18: note: candidate is:
temp2.cpp:25:6: note: template<class T, class U> B<U> operator+(const A<T>&, const A<T>&)
 B<U> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)
      ^
temp2.cpp:25:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
temp2.cpp:33:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’
   B<double> c = a+b;
```

Comment: Does "fail to compile" mean that you get an error message?  What is the error message?

Comment: "`couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’`" seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Unrelated, I can't fathom why you wrote the version with two template parameters, it won't compile/work unless they're the same anyway.

Comment: How did you expect `U` to be deduced?

Comment: @MooingDuck, obviously this was a piece of code meant to illustrate something I did not understand.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I had assumed the return type would also be used in the deduction.

Comment: @Pradhan: Just thinking about it logically, how could a computer decide what you wanted `U` to be, in that situation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit when it sees the expression B<double> c = a+b, it knows the expected return type, doesn't it? Would it be impossible to factor that into the deduction?

Comment: @Pradhan: Firstly, what you end up _doing_ with the `a+b` is not taken into consideration, and quite rightly so, for reasons that would take too long to explain here. Secondly, in some cases it's technically feasible, but what if you wrote `auto c`? What if there were multiple types `B<X>` visible that had valid implicit conversions to `B<double>`? What then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That makes sense to me. Thanks for the short explanation.

Comment: Just for fun: You *can* actually simulate overloading on the return type. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e24b7bde666c2f5) which actually compiles. Generalizing it for expressions like `a+(2*b)/c` is more complicated (although not impossible ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling you why it failed:

> temp2.cpp:25:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   temp2.cpp:33:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’

The template parameter `U` only appears in the return type of the function template, and so it cannot be deduced. Your code will compile if you explicitly list the template arguments

```
B<double> c = operator+<double, double>(a, b);
```

---

And if you swap the order of the template parameters so that `U` appears before `T`, you can still allow `T` to be deduced.

```
template<typename U, typename T>
B<U> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)
{
  return (B<U>)t + (B<U>)u;
}

B<double> c = operator+<double>(a, b);
```

---

The commented out `operator+` implementation works because the return type is also using the same type argument `T`, thus allowing it to be deduced from the function template arguments.

Comment: Ah ok. I had assumed the return type would be part of the deduction as well. Thanks!

Comment: That's logically infeasible (in the general case).

Answer (score 5):

In

```
B<double> c = a+b;
```

the type template parameter `U` in

```
B<U> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)
```

cannot be deduced. `U` will not be deduced as `double` simply because the result of the call is being assigned to `B<double>`. You would have to explicitly specify `U` as `double`, for example by the following,

```
B<double> c = operator+<double, double>(a, b);
```

Now obviously this is likely not a desirable situation. So what can you do? Well, it's hard to say because you haven't specified what `A` and `B` are to be used for. But, as you've already discovered, your code compiles with the commented-out operator,

```
template<typename T>
B<T> operator+(A<T> const& t, A<T> const& u)
{
    return (B<T>)t + (B<T>)u;
}
```

For some reason you seem to want it to be possible to use the result to initialize a `B<U>` where `U` might not be the same as `T`, so perhaps the right solution is to make it possible to construct `B<U>` from `B<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
  template <typename U>
  B(const B<U>& rhs) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

(You likely also want to write a similar assignment operator.)

Comment: The first line of this is misleading. The `B<double> =` in fact has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The error message from the compiler is clear. It is not able to deduce parameter `U` to instantiate the `operator+` function.

You can be explicit by using:

```
B<double> c = operator+<double, double>(a,b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Return types are not deduced.

You can fake it with expression templates.

```
template<template<class>class Op, class Rhs, class Lhs>
struct deferred{
    Lhs lhs; Rhs rhs;
    template<typename Result>
    operator Result() const { return Op<Result>{}( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ); }
};

template<class R> sum;
template<class U> sum<B<U>>{
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  B<U> operator()( A<Lhs> const& lhs, A<Rhs> const& rhs )const{
    return B<Lhs>(lhs)+B<Rhs>(rhs);
  }
};
template<class T>
deferred<sum, A<T>const&, A<T>const&> operator+( A<T>const& a, A<T>const& b){
  return {a,b};
}
```

which should give you the idea.